# Convert Shortcut Hotkey combination to real keys?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapi, hotkeys, keyboard-shortcuts

How I could convert the Hotkey property of a shortcut to represent the combination in String type or directly convert the value to the right combination?

I'm using the `IShellLink` interface to retrieve info from shortcuts.

```
Private Shared lnk_hotkey As Short

interface IShellLinkW...
    Sub GetHotkey(ByRef pwHotkey As Short)
    Sub SetHotkey(ByVal wHotkey As Short)
end interface...

function to retrieve the hotkey...
    DirectCast(lnk, IPersistFile).Load(ShortcutFile, 0) ' Load the shortcut
    DirectCast(lnk, IShellLinkW).GetHotkey(lnk_hotkey) ' Retrieve the Hotkey
    Return lnk_hotkey ' Return the hotkey
end function...
```

Now, I have a shortcut which for the Hotkey property has this:

```
CONTROL + ALT + A
```

Well, the `Keys` enumeration says this:

```
  Keys.ControlKey = 17
  Keys.Alt = 262144
  Keys.A = 65
```

So for a combination like `Keys.ControlKey Or Keys.Alt Or Keys.A` sums a total of: `262226`, but the IShellLink returns a `1601`, Then what kind of key representation is used this?

I need both a solution to represent right the shortcut hotkey and also to set a new custom hotkey for the `Sub SetHotkey(ByVal wHotkey As Short)` mehotd.

> EDIT:

Oh, And this is what I've tried:

```
    Dim ShortcutInfo As Shortcut.ShortcutInfo =
        Shortcut.GetInfo("File.lnk")

    MsgBox(ShortcutInfo.Hotkey) ' Result: 1601

    MsgBox([Enum].Parse(GetType(Keys), ShortcutInfo.Hotkey).ToString)
    ' Result: 1601

    Dim k As New KeysConverter
    MsgBox(k.ConvertToString(1601).ToString)
    ' Result: (empty)
```

> UPDATE:

I'm trying it...

First I've added this Enumeration:

```
Public Enum HotkeyModifiers As Short
    SHIFT = 1
    CONTROL = 2
    ALT = 4
End Enum
```

So the process should automatize the task, but I don't know what to do now here:

```
Public Shared Sub CreateShortcut(blah blah blah... 
                                 ByVal HotKey As Tuple(Of HotkeyModifiers, Keys))

MsgBox(CInt(HotKey.Item1 & HotKey.Item2))
' Result: 665

' I need to translate the 665 into the right value, 1601.

end sub
```

This is how I call the method:

```
Shortcut.CreateShortcut(Tuple.Create(HotkeyModifiers.CONTROL Or HotkeyModifiers.ALT, Keys.A))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CommCtrl.h there is:

```
#define HOTKEYF_SHIFT           0x01
#define HOTKEYF_CONTROL         0x02
#define HOTKEYF_ALT             0x04
```

1601 is 641 in hexa.

Low Order Byte is 0x41, 65 in decimal: 'A'

High Order Byte is 0x06, that is HOTKEYF_CONTROL + HOTKEYF_ALT.

To Set the hoy Key to SHIFT+CONTROL+B, use 0x342 (834)

AFAIK, you can't use KeysConverter with the combination of the two bytes.
Use KeysConverter for the low order byte, and manualy add the modifiers keys from the high order byte.

The [IShellLink::SetHotkey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761045.aspx) documentation states:

> ```
> wHotkey
> Type: WORD
> The new keyboard shortcut. The virtual key code is in the low-order byte,
> and the modifier flags are in the high-order byte. The modifier flags can be
> a combination of the values specified in the description of
> the IShellLink::GetHotkey method.
> ```

You have to make a 16 bits value, with the lower 8 bits set to a Key, and the upper 8 bits made of a bitwise combination of the 3 possible modifiers.

Comment: Thankyou for all the information, but I need a little more help to make this, you've said how to translate the 1601, but also I need is to translate the Keys enum combination (262226 number) to that 1601, which steps I need to do?. To give you an example, I would like to set the hotkey like this `Dim hotkey = Keys.ControlKey Or Keys.Shift Or Keys.A` then the process of translating those keys to the right value (1601) need to be automatized and not manually

Comment: I've updated my question adding a new code, please see the update, thanks.

Comment: Done!: `DirectCast(lnk, IShellLinkW).SetHotkey(Convert.ToInt32(CInt(HotKey.Item1 & Hex(HotKey.Item2)), 16))`